# How to write select query in switchoffset()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to write select query inside the

> SWITCHOFFSET()

example

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-04:00')
```

i need

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), select timezone from mytable)
```

how can i do this things?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), timezone)
FROM mytable
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details, then. Update your question with sample data and expected results versus the result you got.

Comment: my question is simple inside the switchoffset()i want to write select query..how can i do?

Comment: You can't put a query inside an expression unless the query only returns one element of one row.

Comment: Step back a level. Instead of focusing on how to write the query the way you tried, what are you trying to accomplish?